# only rotate button and not it's text on button click

Tags: html, css

I rotate a button on click:

```
<button class="btn" type="button">Go</button>
```

css:

```
.btn:focus {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

now the problem is `txt` also rotates on `btn` click. How can I don't rotate the `txt` or rotate it 360 on button click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the button text in a `span`, and rotate that on `:focus` of the `button` by another 180 degree:

```css
.btn:focus {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.btn:focus span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" type="button"><span>Go</span></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the text with a `span` and rotate it to the other direction:

```css
.btn:focus {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.btn:focus > span {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" type="button">
  <span>Go</span>
</button>
```